# How to enable bluetooth without restarting OS?

Tags: bluetooth

I have a problem with bluetooth in Ubuntu 13.04. The bluetooth won't work until I restart my laptop. I've tried:

```
hciconfig hci0 reset
hciconfig hci0 up
service bluetooth start
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
```

Also you can try [BlueZ](http://www.bluez.org/)

> BlueZ provides support for the core Bluetooth layers and protocols. It
>   is flexible, efficient and uses a modular implementation.

To install

```
sudo apt-get install bluez
```

Comment: I've installed bluez and restart bluetooth service. but when i open bluetooth from System Settings it shows that bluetooth is disable and i'm not able to add a device to list.

Comment: Have you tried running Bluetooth manager from Dash?

Comment: yes but i still can't get gnome-bluetooth GUI to work. By the way, i tried hcitool. i can find remote devices with this command.

Comment: Is there a Bluetooth hardware switch?

Comment: No. I have a Asus u41sv laptop.there is no Hardware switch except Fn + F2.

Comment: Add the output of `rfkill list all`to your question.

Comment: 0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: yes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9949/discussion-between-babak-and-mitch)

Answer (score 2):

So if you really want to "reset" everything this will do it.  It requires sudo, or use

```
sudo su
```

Then just reset the module.

```
hciconfig hci0 down
rmmod btusb
modprobe btusb
hciconfig hci0 up
```

This works for me when my bluetooth crashes and some how still holds on to resources.  Simply resetting the service is not enough.